# Are ChromeOS and ChromeOS Flex questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

[ChromeOS](https://www.google.com/intl/en_uk/chromebook/chrome-os/) is the Linux-based operating system that is found on Chromebooks, made by Google. It uses the Google Chrome browser as the main interface.

[ChromeOS Flex](https://chromeenterprise.google/os/chromeosflex/) is the same operating system meant for installation on PCs and Apple computers, and is provided for free.

ChromeOS is not considered a typical GNU/Linux distribution like Debian or Fedora, because the main interface is just the Chrome browser. So my question is: are questions about using ChromeOS and ChromeOS Flex on-topic here at Unix & Linux StackExchange? If they are not on-topic here, which StackExchange website would they be a good fit for?

Tags: [chrome-os](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome-os)

Answer (score 3):

It's not designed to expose much of a Unix OS.  I think superuser.com will be the best match in many cases.  It has tags for:

- [chromebook](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chromebook)
- [chrome-os](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-os)
- [chrome-os-flex](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-os-flex)

If you hit a limitation with the system for running "Linux apps", maybe you'd get some lucky guesses on U&L, but maybe more along the lines of "why might this not work" than "how can I reasonably achieve my goal here".

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it's worth drawing a hard and fast line; chromeos crosses the line between Linux and Chrome.  It might be simple to say that anything done in crosh might be suitable, but that's hard to put into a rule.

Comment: We have something similar for Android, where only the Unix-y parts of Android are on-topic, IIRC.